# Laravel/Mysql: unable to set field to null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

I am working on a laravel project and trying to duplicate a record in mysql db.
after replication I want to set a field value to null(appointment_status).
everything is working except the new record's value (appointment_status) is the same as the original record even tho I set it to null.

```
    $newAppointment = $appointment->replicate();
    //push to get the id for the cloned record
    $newAppointment->push();
    $newAppointment->duplicated_from_id = $appointment->id;
    $newAppointment->appointment_status = null;
    $newAppointment->save();
    //updating the old appointment
    $appointment->duplicated_to_id = $newAppointment->id;
    $appointment->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of whole code-block, try something like this:

```
// replicate as the new record with some different fields
$newAppointment = $appointment->replicate()->fill([
    'duplicated_from_id' => $appointment->id,
    'appointment_status' => null,
])->save();

// update some fields of initial original record
$appointment->update([
    'duplicated_to_id' => $newAppointment->id,
]);
```

For more check out [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#replicating-models).